# Алгоритм "Шифр Хилла "

Tags: алгоритм, шифрование

Надо реализовать шифр Хилла с матрицей 3х3.
Проблема:
Неправильно считается обратная матрица(
Из этого примера [wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шифр_Хилла) матрица у меня получается такая (и вручную и программно):
8  5 21
21 8 14
10 5 8
Как они ее там получили? Я считаю: `(1/det)*A[3][3]`, где `det` - детерминант, `A[3][3]` - матрица дополнений. Если элемент отрицательный прибавляю 26 пока он не станет положительным, а затем остальные элементы по модулю 26. Детерминант сходится (det=441), решение сравнения сходится (x=25), а вот матрица в итоге нет.

Если надо - выложу код. Но дело не в нем, а непонимании подсчета обратной матрицы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы, видимо, не так берете обратный детерминант.

Предполагаю, что вы правильно вычислили матрицу обратных дополнений. Первая строка в ней

```
70 5 -99.
```

После приведения по модулю 26 получаем

```
18 5 5.
```

Умножаем на `1/det(A)`. Обратите внимание, что тут не просто деление, а мультиплкативная инверсия, поэтому они там в примере для нее и получили 25. [Считать можно через расширенный алгоритм Евклида](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). Поищите "multiplicative inverse {your language}", наверняка что-то найдете (в Java можно воспользоваться встроенным `BigInteger.modInverse`).
Так вот, умножаем на 25:

```
450 125 125.
```

Сравниваем по модулю с 26:

```
8 21 21.
```

После транспонирования это будет первый столбец.

Comment: Это уже больше похоже на правду...

Answer (score 1):

Есть под рукой код метода Гаусса с приписыванием единичной матрицы. В результате работы в массиве `E` получается обратная матрица.

```
int N;
int i, j, k;

ifstream infile("matrix.txt");
infile >> N;

double *A = new double[N*N];

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        infile >> A[i*N+j];

double *E = new double[N*N];
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
        E[i*N+j] = 0;
    E[i*N+i] = 1;
}

double pivot;
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    pivot = A[i*N+i];
    for( j = 0; j < N; j++ ) {
        A[i*N+j] /= pivot;
        E[i*N+j] /= pivot;
    }

    for( j = 0; j < N; j++ ) {
        if ( i == j ) continue;

        pivot = A[j*N+i];
        for( k = 0; k < N; k++ ) {
            A[j*N+k] -= (A[i*N+k]*pivot);
            E[j*N+k] -= (E[i*N+k]*pivot);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Там вся арифметика ведется по модулю 26.

Comment: Будет время - сделаю вариант с модульной арифметикой.